# Is there a pure bash way to eliminate some external commands in my use case?

Tags: regex, bash, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running OS X 10.8.5 so the `rename` command is not an option and what I've coded fits in with what the rest of the *bash* script is doing so I'd prefer to stay within this framework but modify it a bit, if possible. I am however using a later version of *bash* then the OS X 10.8.5 shipping default, I'm using GNU *bash* 4.3.30 that I installed from source code. (*Yes I know I'm a few patches behind.*)

What I'd like to do in the *function* below, if possible, is to replace the `mv`'s command *target* argument which is using *command substitution* with something totaly in *pure bash*.  More specifically I'd like to eliminate the use of *pipes* and *external executables*.

**Question:** Can the *command substitution* I'm using either be modified or replaced with *filename expansion* and or *pattern matching* not using *pipes* or *external executables* to achieve my stated goal? *(Or something else more reasonable.)*

- I've read the three related sections in the Bash Reference Manual however I have to admit I didn't readily see how it might be possible.  Although I did try recoding it a few times however the output was not at all what I wanted, it was either mangled *filenames* or the error `... bad substitution`.
- All target *filenames* in the *working directory* will either already match `RegEx.$ext` or will be `RegEx+foobar.$ext` and the way I've coded the *function* and using `mv` is if it's not already matching the `RegEx` it renames the target *filenames* from `RegEx+foobar.$ext` to `RegEx.$ext`.  All *filenames* when truncated *will be unique*, so there is no need to worry about overwriting an existing `RegEx.$ext` *filename* and hence no additional *error checking* needed.

**Example Filenames:** filenameC01P01.png filenameC01P02foobar.jpg filenameC01P03.tif

**Expected Output:** `filenameC01P02foobar.jpg` -> `filenameC01P02.jpg`

**Code:**

```
function truncate_filenames () {
  for f in *.png *.jpg *.tif; do
      if [[ -f $f ]]; then
          ext="${f:(-3)}"
          if [[ ! ${f%.*} =~ .*C[0-9]{2}P[0-9]{2}$ ]]; then
              mv -v "$f" "$(echo "$f" | grep -Eo '.*C[0-9]{2}P[0-9]{2}').$ext"
          fi
      fi
  done
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you just want to strip anything following the `CxxPxx` template, but preserve the extension.

```
# Capture both the good part and the trailing garbage
[[ ${f%.*} =~ (.*C[0-9]{2}P[0-9]{2})(.*)$ ]]
if [[ -n ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]]; then
    mv -v "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.$ext"
fi
```

You can probably capture the extension in the regular expression as well, eliminating the need to extract it separately.

```
[[ $f =~ (.*C[0-9]{2}P[0-9]{2})(.*)\.(.*)$ ]]
if [[ -n ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]]; then
    mv -v "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
```

Comment: Looks like I'll need to read up on BASH_REMATCH. What other mechanisms (for lack of the proper term) are in use in your code so I may read in the manual to understand and then implement what your code is doing. In other words the parentheses in `(.*C[0-9]{2}P[0-9]{2})(.*)$` its usage in this case is called what? Is that covered under BASH_REMATCH in the manual? Also in the second example `foobar` after the `RegEx` can contain dots, e.g. `filenameC01P02foo.bar.jpg`, so does that change what `[[ $f =~ (.*C[0-9]{2}P[0-9]{2})(.*)\.(.*)$ ]]` is doing?  In other words is the `(.*)$` portion greedy?

Comment: The parentheses just form capture groups, whose contents are stored in `BASH_REMATCH`, so reading about that should be sufficient. `.*` is greedy, so the one before the literal `.` should consume as much as it can, leaving only a single extension for the final instance.

Comment: I've tested both permutations and of course each work as expected. Even thought I don't yet understand fully what/how it's doing it nonetheless I'm quite comfortable in implementing the code you've provided.  I will read up a bit more in the Bash Reference Manual and other sources to more fully understand. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I more fully get it now as I originally glossed over "_The element of BASH_REMATCH with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression._" in the Bash Reference Manual, which upon rereading clears up the offset in indexing I was seeing in the elements of the array created from the capture groups.  I was (wrongly) expecting to see `"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}.$ext"` and `"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` however `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.$ext"` and `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"` make perfect sense now. :)